# RxJS switchMap, flatMap and mergeMap in category theory

Tags: functional-programming, rxjs, reactive-programming, category-theory

In a simple put, a monad is an object with `flatMap()`. What are `switchMap()` and `mergeMap` from the perspective of category theory?

Comment: Other monads :-)

Comment: @Bergi does it make `Observable` a special kind of monad?

Comment: `switchMap` keeps state which would make it suspicious to me as a monad.